# Coefficient omitted due to time fixed effect and multi-collinearity

Tags: financial-economics, paneldata, fixed-effects

I am working on a research paper (my first one) where I am dealing with company level unbalanced panel data. There are broadly two types of control variables in the study - a) firm level control variables (market cap, return on assets, cash holdings etc.) which varies for a firm cross-sectionally as well as in time and (b) macro variables (risk free rate, excess market return etc.) which do not vary cross-sectionally across firm level but vary only across the time. When I run the regression in STATA, I get an estimated coefficient of ‘0’ for macro-economic variables if I take the time and industry fixed effect. The stata provides the warning message that such variables are perfectly correlated with the fixed effects, hence cannot be estimated and provides ‘0’ coefficients for such variables. This serial correlation is understood because the values of these control variables will remain same for the time fixed effect dummy across all the firms.  Hence, when I remove the time fixed effects, then as expected this issue does not occur and I get the estimated coefficients.
Similar macro-economic variables are used in the other studies then the results always mention that the time fixed effects and cross-sectional fixed effects are being considered. I am not able to understand why these studies did not face the same issue that I am facing?
I have tried looking in books, forums etc but did not get any inputs on this. I think I am missing something conceptually, and not able to find the correct explanation. Please let me know if I can refer to something specific to resolve this.

Comment: Hello @jaitri and welcome to the site. Would you consider formatting your prose a bit when asking a question? This would help you most of all, since you'd enable people to read your prompts with ease, and probably answer them too. Of course this is not necessary, but it should help you loads. You can edit your question at any time.

Comment: Also double posting is not welcome, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499689/coefficient-omitted-due-to-time-fixed-effect-and-multi-collinearity.